# Skrollr destroy canceling out height 100% on body

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, height, skrollr

Ok so I am using bootstrap 3 and skrollr.js and I have a fullscreen hero unit at the top of my page, which has a simple skrollr parallax effect on it. I also have some js which "activates" and "destroys" skrollr at 768 width. This works fine, but when I size the browser window down the `height:100%` just is not applied to the body for some reason.

I believe the issue is somewhere within my js for skrollr which is:

```
$(function () {

  // initialize skrollr if the window width is large enough
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    skrollr.init({forceHeight: false,smoothScrolling: true, smoothScrollingDuration: 1500});
  }

  // disable skrollr if the window is resized below 768px wide
  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
      skrollr.init().destroy(); // skrollr.init() returns the singleton created above
    }
  });

});
```

I have tried adjusting the js in various way and still have not found a solution, I am currently looking for different ways to disable skrollr on touch devices.

**[You can view the js fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4n58C/5/)**

If you size the window down to mobile size you will see the hero unit get smaller and not fullscreen. But if you refresh it works fine, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So I fixed this by adding `!important` to `height: 100%;` but now skrollr does not turn on when I size the browser back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `!important` to `height:100%;` on the **body** and **html** tag.

And also changing my start-skrollr.js to:

```
$(function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    skrollr.init({forceHeight: false,smoothScrolling: true, smoothScrollingDuration: 1500});
  }
});
```

The last part of my .js file was not needed.